# Silverlight shows blank page instead of throwing exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I am facing an issue that due to some missing styles, when I run my Silverlight 4 application it simply shows a blank page instead of throwing an exception and telling me which style is missing. Any suggestions??

Comment: Have you tried running under debugger and analyzing the debug output? Does it say something about the error?

Comment: It does not say anything about the error other than
The program '[5348] chrome.exe: Silverlight' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: And what if you run it under, say, IE? Does it also crash silently?

Comment: The built in IE debugger throws an exception. Awesome!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, seems like the answer is:

When debugging Silverlight, try using different browsers. Pay special attention to IE since it is somewhat integrated with other Microsoft software, including VS.